# unrecognized selector sent to instance when trying to set the "username" property of PFInstallation

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

When a user logs in, I want the `PFInstallation` "username" property to be set to a string, so that  the user's `Parse.Installation` object on the Parse server has a "username" property of that same string.

When I attempt to do this below, I get an error stating:

`[PFInstallation setUsername:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x155af830`

I don't see why I'm getting this error, as I set the `username` property in `PFInstallation.h` to be an `NSString`, and I'm setting it to a string.

**PFInstallation.h:**

```
/// The username for the PFInstallation.
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *username;
```

**AppDelegate.m:**

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application

    didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
    {
        // Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
        PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
        [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
        currentInstallation.channels = @[@"noPush"];
        currentInstallation.username = @"exampleUsername";
        [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe You are trying to **change the header for a compiled library**.

The header file is there to tell the app what is inside the library. Modifying it, **won't change the library inside** - it will only tell Your app to expect something that isn't there.

I would recommend to use a `category` or extend that class. See: [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html)

Comment: Exactly: I suggest to extend the class if you want set up this property...or (if you really need this other solution) use a category.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through their documentation, I don't see a *username* property.

https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFInstallation.html

If you added that to the .h file, but don't have access to the .m file, I wouldn't recommend simply adding it and trying to set it, you don't know what they are doing under the covers.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to look at the `PFUser` class, which *does* have a `username` property. You can get at it like this:

```
[[PFUser currentUser] setUsername:@"username"];
```

Alternatively, you can use the Parse data browser to add a `username` field to the PFInstallation object, and then you can set it like this:

```
[[PFInstallation currentInstallation] setObject:@"aUsername" forKey:@"username"];
```